# Can i use amasty extension with Request for quote extension in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to use the Amasty extension order attributes with the request for quote extension in magento website. Please let us know i am facing problem . how we can do this.
here is the [link](https://rentalbookingsoftware.com/request-quote-module-extension-2/) of request for quote extension and 
this is the [link](https://amasty.com/order-attributes.html) of amasty extension.

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site. Please post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information